# How to control Langchain OPENAI_MULTI_FUNCTIONS Agent to make it reconize all gmauthe inputs?

Tags: openai-api, agent, langchain, py-langchain

I have setup a OPENAI_MULTI_FUNCTIONS Agent which seems to do great with a few token, but even if all the information are in the prompt, it is not able to use them for the tool input.

(Tis topic has the same base as an other on, but use different agent, and face different issues)

What is the issue - I have two custom tools:

- CustomJiraTicketWriting which use FewShotChatMessagePromptTemplate and StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas in order to produce dictionary output with a compatible & developed JSON representing a Jira ticket.
- CustomJiraTicketPOST which accept 4 inputs : ticket / email / url / token in order to POST the ticket on Jira. Both of these function works great separately, but when I use an Structured_Chat_Zero_Shot_Description agent to create a ReACT decision, it appears that the Agent refuse to use any of the tools.

I presented below, the agent use the first tools, write the ticket, inject it in the new prompt, but after that, the agent decide to use the second tool but miss some information

My setup :

Name: langchain Version: 0.0.308 Summary: Building applications with LLMs through composability Home-page: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain Author: Author-email: License: MIT Location: /Users/cgm_mbf_lemery_mac/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.10/site-packages Requires: aiohttp, anyio, async-timeout, dataclasses-json, jsonpatch, langsmith, numpy, pydantic, PyYAML, requests, SQLAlchemy, tenacity Required-by: langchain-experimental, langflow, langfuse

```
import os
import json
import langchain
import requests
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from typing import Optional, Type
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from langchain.agents import (AgentType, 
                              initialize_agent, )
from langchain.cache import InMemoryCache
from langchain.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from langchain.chains import LLMChain, SequentialChain
from langchain.output_parsers import (ResponseSchema, 
                                      StructuredOutputParser)

from langchain.tools import BaseTool
from langchain.prompts import (ChatPromptTemplate,
                               MessagesPlaceholder,
                               FewShotChatMessagePromptTemplate)

from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.schema import (SystemMessage,
                             )


from langchain.callbacks.manager import (
    AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun,
    CallbackManagerForToolRun,
)

debug_mode = True
langchain.debug = True

email = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
url = "https://XXXXXXXXXX.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue"

langchain.llm_cache = InMemoryCache()

os.environ["JIRA_API_TOKEN"]= 'XXXXXXXXXX'
api_token_jira = os.environ["JIRA_API_TOKEN"]
os.environ["JIRA_USERNAME"]= 'XXXXXXXXXX'
os.environ["JIRA_INSTANCE_URL"] = "XXXXXXXXXX"
site_jira = os.environ["JIRA_INSTANCE_URL"]
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']='XXXXXXXXXX'
openai_api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

model_name = 'gpt-3.5-turbo'
temperature = 0.0


model_llm = OpenAI(model_name=model_name, 
                   temperature=temperature, 
                   max_tokens=3500)

turbo_llm = ChatOpenAI(
    temperature=temperature,
    model_name=model_name,
    max_tokens=3100,)


class SummaryTicket(BaseModel):
    """Input for writing Jira Ticket"""
    summary: str = Field(..., description="ticket summary")
    

class POST(BaseModel):
    """Input for POST a ticket"""
    ticket: str = Field(..., description="Jira ticket as a dictionary")
    email: str = Field(..., description="email associated with the Jira Software account")
    url: str = Field(..., description="url to POST a Jira ticket at")
    token : str = Field(..., description="Identification JIRA API token") 

class CustomJiraTicketWriting(BaseTool):
    name = "Jira_Ticket_Write"
    description = ("""
        Useful to transform a summary into a real JSON Jira ticket.
        The input should be like :
        {{
            Action: Ticket_writing,
            Action Input: 
                "summary": <ticket summary>, 
        }}
        """)


    def _run(self, 
            summary: str,
            run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun] = None,
             ) -> dict:
        
        response_schema = ResponseSchema(
            name="ticket",
            description="Jira ticket information",
            structure={
                "fields": {
                    "project": {
                        "key": str
                    },
                    "summary": str,
                    "issuetype": {
                        "name": str
                    },
                    "priority": {
                        "name": str
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": str,
                        "version": int,
                        "content": [
                        {
                            "type": str,
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": str,
                                    "text": str
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": str,
                            "attrs": {
                                "level": int
                            },
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": str,
                                    "text": str
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        response_schemas=[response_schema]
        output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)
        format_instructions = output_parser.get_format_instructions()     
        


        examples = [
          {
            "Jira_Ticket_Summary" : "Creation of the MySQL database",
            "output": """{"fields":{"project":{"key":"AJ"},"summary":"Create a Jira ticket to integrate my MySQL database into our current assets","issuetype":{"name":"Story"},"priority":{"name":"High"},"description":{"type":"doc","version":1,"content":[{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"As a developer, I want to integrate my MySQL database with our current assets to improve data management."}]},{"type":"heading","attrs":{"level":2},"content":[{"type":"text","text":"Acceptance Criteria:"}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- The MySQL database is successfully integrated with the application."}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- Data can be efficiently stored and retrieved from the integrated MySQL database."}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- The integration process follows best practices and security standards."}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- The integration is documented for future reference."}]},{"type":"heading","attrs":{"level":2},"content":[{"type":"text","text":"Subtasks:"}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- Analyze the structure of the MySQL database."}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- Create integration scripts for data migration."}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- Implement data synchronization with the application."}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- Perform testing and quality assurance of the integration."}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"- Document the integration process and configurations."}]}]}}"""
          }]

        example_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
            [
          ("human", "{Jira_Ticket_Summary}"),
            ("ai", "{output}")]
        )


        few_shot_prompt = FewShotChatMessagePromptTemplate(
            example_prompt=example_prompt,
            examples=examples,
        )  


        prompt_string = """
        Jira_Ticket_Summary: {Jira_Ticket_Summary}

        {format_instructions}
        """

        prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
            [
                ("system", "You are a Jira assistant specialized in creating technical tickets. You always develop the tickets with precise examples of sub-tasks and acceptance criteria. Remember to use double quotes for keys."),
                few_shot_prompt,
                ("human", prompt_string),
            ]
        )

        final_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate(
            messages=[
               prompt  
            ],
            input_variables=['Jira_Ticket_Summary'],
            partial_variables={"format_instructions": format_instructions},
            output_parser=output_parser
        )


        chain = LLMChain(llm=turbo_llm, 
                         prompt=final_prompt,
                         output_parser=output_parser,
                         output_key="ticket")

        sequential_chain = SequentialChain(chains=[chain],
                                           input_variables=['Jira_Ticket_Summary'],
                                           output_variables=['ticket'],
                                           verbose=True)

        input_data={'Jira_Ticket_Summary' : f'{summary}'}

        result = sequential_chain(input_data)

        print("\n\n\n result_writing : ",result)
        print("\n\n\n result_writing_type : ",type(result),'\n\n\n')
        return json.dumps(result['ticket'])
        
    def _arun(self, 
            summary:str,
            run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun] = None,
             ) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError("This tool does not support async")
    
    args_schema: Optional[Type[BaseModel]] = SummaryTicket
        

class ≠(BaseTool):

    name = "Jira_Ticket_Post"
    description = ("""\
                Useful to POST a ticket in Jira Software after you wrote it.
                The input should be like :
        {{
            Action: Jira_Post,
            Action Input: 
                "ticket": <JSON of the ticket>,
                "email": <email associated with the Jira Software account>,
                "url": <url to POST the ticket at>,
                "token": <identification JIRA API token>
        }}
        """)

    def _run(
        self,
        ticket: str, 
        email: str,
        url: str,
        token: str,
        run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun] = None
    ) -> str:

        # Retrieve the values using lowercase keys
        ticket = json.loads(ticket)
        body = ticket['Jira_ticket']

        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(email, api_token_jira)

        headers = {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

        response = requests.request(
           "POST",
           url,
           data=json.dumps(body),
           headers=headers,
           auth=auth
        )
        print("\n\nPOST : ", json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")), "\n\n")
        
        return json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": "))
    
    async def _arun(
        self,
        ticket: str, 
        email: str,
        url: str,
        token: str,
        run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun] = None,
    ) -> str:
        """Use the tool asynchronously."""
        raise NotImplementedError("custom_search does not support async")
        
    args_schema: Optional[Type[BaseModel]] = POST


PREFIX = """You are a Jira Assistant.
You're designed to assist the user with a wide range of tasks related to Jira object management. 
It goes from understand the user's need for its tickets, writing technical and detailed Jira tickets with descriptions, subtasks and acceptance criteria’s to realize API call (POST, PUT or GET) with Jira objects.
Create a ticket means Write it then POST it.
Before to act, retrieve the inputs you need in the prompt.
"""


chat_history = MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history")
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key="chat_history", 
    return_messages=True)

agent_kwargs = {
    "system_message": SystemMessage(content=f"{PREFIX}"),
    "input_variables": ["chat_history"]
}


tools = [CustomJiraTicketPOST(),CustomJiraTicketWriting()]

conversational_agent = initialize_agent(
    agent=AgentType.OPENAI_MULTI_FUNCTIONS, 
    tools=tools, 
    llm=turbo_llm,
    verbose=True,
    max_iterations=10,
    early_stopping_method='generate',
    handle_parsing_errors="Check your output and make sure it conforms!",
    memory=memory,
    agent_kwargs=agent_kwargs
)

payload = {\
    "summary":"Create a ticket to connect our backend to a new MySQL database. The project key is AJ",\
    "email":f"{email}",\
    "url":f"{url}",\
    "token":f"{api_token_jira}",
}

answer = conversational_agent.run(json.dumps(payload))
```

**Expected behaviour :**

- an 201 code for created ticket on Jira Software

**Actuel behaviour :**

```
File ~/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py:501, in Chain.run(self, callbacks, tags, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
    499     if len(args) != 1:
    500         raise ValueError("`run` supports only one positional argument.")
--> 501     return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
    502         _output_key
    503     ]
    505 if kwargs and not args:
    506     return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
...
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
url
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
token
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

And about the prompt

```
[llm/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 4:llm:ChatOpenAI] Entering LLM run with input:
{
  "prompts": [
    "System: You are a Jira Assistant.\nYou're designed to assist the user with a wide range of tasks related to Jira object management. \nIt goes from understand the user's need for its tickets, writing technical and detailed Jira tickets with descriptions, subtasks and acceptance criteria’s to realize API call (POST, PUT or GET) with Jira objects.\nCreate a ticket means Write it then POST it.\nBefore to act, retrieve the inputs you need in the prompt.\n\nHuman: {\"summary\": \"Create a ticket to connect our backend to a new MySQL database. The project key is AJ\", \"email\": \"XXXXXXX@gmail.com\", \"url\": \"https://XXXXXXXX.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue\", \"token\": \"XXXXXXXXX\"}\nAI: {'name': 'tool_selection', 'arguments': '{\\n  \"actions\": [\\n    {\\n      \"action_name\": \"Jira_Ticket_Write\",\\n      \"action\": {\\n        \"summary\": \"Create a ticket to connect our backend to a new MySQL database. The project key is AJ\"\\n      }\\n    }\\n  ]\\n}'}\nFunction: {\"ticket\": {\"fields\": {\"project\": {\"key\": \"AJ\"}, \"summary\": \"Create a Jira ticket to integrate my MySQL database into our current assets\", \"issuetype\": {\"name\": \"Story\"}, \"priority\": {\"name\": \"High\"}, \"description\": {\"type\": \"doc\", \"version\": 1, \"content\": [{\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"As a developer, I want to integrate my MySQL database with our current assets to improve data management.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"heading\", \"attrs\": {\"level\": 2}, \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"Acceptance Criteria:\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- The MySQL database is successfully integrated with the application.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- Data can be efficiently stored and retrieved from the integrated MySQL database.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- The integration process follows best practices and security standards.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- The integration is documented for future reference.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"heading\", \"attrs\": {\"level\": 2}, \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"Subtasks:\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- Analyze the structure of the MySQL database.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- Create integration scripts for data migration.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- Implement data synchronization with the application.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- Perform testing and quality assurance of the integration.\"}]}, {\"type\": \"paragraph\", \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"- Document the integration process and configurations.\"}]}]}}}}"
  ]
}
[llm/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 4:llm:ChatOpenAI] [83.60s] Exiting LLM run with output:
{
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": "",
        "generation_info": {
          "finish_reason": "function_call"
        },
        "message": {
          "lc": 1,
          "type": "constructor",
          "id": [
            "langchain",
            "schema",
            "messages",
            "AIMessage"
          ],
          "kwargs": {
            "content": "",
            "additional_kwargs": {
              "function_call": {
                "name": "tool_selection",
                "arguments": "{\n  \"actions\": [\n    {\n      \"action_name\": \"Jira_Ticket_Post\",\n      \"action\": {\n        \"ticket\": \"{\\\"fields\\\": {\\\"project\\\": {\\\"key\\\": \\\"AJ\\\"}, \\\"summary\\\": \\\"Create a Jira ticket to integrate my MySQL database into our current assets\\\", \\\"issuetype\\\": {\\\"name\\\": \\\"Story\\\"}, \\\"priority\\\": {\\\"name\\\": \\\"High\\\"}, \\\"description\\\": {\\\"type\\\": \\\"doc\\\", \\\"version\\\": 1, \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"As a developer, I want to integrate my MySQL database with our current assets to improve data management.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"heading\\\", \\\"attrs\\\": {\\\"level\\\": 2}, \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"Acceptance Criteria:\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- The MySQL database is successfully integrated with the application.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- Data can be efficiently stored and retrieved from the integrated MySQL database.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- The integration process follows best practices and security standards.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- The integration is documented for future reference.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"heading\\\", \\\"attrs\\\": {\\\"level\\\": 2}, \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"Subtasks:\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- Analyze the structure of the MySQL database.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- Create integration scripts for data migration.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- Implement data synchronization with the application.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- Perform testing and quality assurance of the integration.\\\"}]}, {\\\"type\\\": \\\"paragraph\\\", \\\"content\\\": [{\\\"type\\\": \\\"text\\\", \\\"text\\\": \\\"- Document the integration process and configurations.\\\"}]}]}}}\"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "llm_output": {
    "token_usage": {
      "prompt_tokens": 916,
      "completion_tokens": 533,
      "total_tokens": 1449
    },
    "model_name": "gpt-3.5-turbo"
  },
  "run": null
}
[chain/error] [1:chain:AgentExecutor] [187.30s] Chain run errored with error:
"ValidationError(model='POST', errors=[{'loc': ('email',), 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ('url',), 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ('token',), 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}])"
```

Thus, all the informations are in the Input, but i has difficulties to use them.
How to handle this situation ?

Best regards